# UIWebViewDelegate cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a cordova-base app (ios), where I have added some native code. 
When cordova had not support to WKWebView I had the web view delegate methods in my viewcontroller and I had control on it, now with the WKWebView plugin i'm not able to set my webview delegate and override his methods.

Someone have resolved this problem?

Comment: Were you able to find any tutorial and convert webview with respect to the latest Cordova lib?